# Handle module dependency in a contrib submodule

Tags: 10

I am maintening a contrib module in which there's a submodule.
This submodule needs commerce_product module to work, but the module doesn't.

In drupal CI pipelines I've got some warnings from phpstan

```
Parameter $commerce_product of method
Drupal\index_now\CommerceProductOperationsInterface::pingIndexNow()
has invalid type Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product.
```

And some errors from phpunit

```
Drupal\Tests\index_now_commerce\Unit\CommerceProductOperationsTest::testProductIsUnpublished
Prophecy\Exception\Doubler\ClassNotFoundException:
Cannot prophesize class Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product, because it cannot be found.
```

I added a composer.json to the submodule

```
{
    "name": "drupal/index_now_commerce",
    "description": "Index now submodule dedicated to commerce products",
    "type": "drupal-module",
    "require": {
        "drupal/core": " ^10",
        "drupal/commerce": "^2.38"
    }
}
```

and the submodule has the dependency

```
dependencies:
  - commerce:commerce_product
```

What can I do more?

Comment: This is slightly related and may lead to some answers: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalci/issues/3250126 It may be that you have to require drupal/commerce in the main module, or perhaps, separate the submodule into its own project.

Comment: _This submodule needs commerce_product module to work, but the module doesn't._ Maybe there's some Drupal-specific practice I'm not familiar with around contrib modules, but that's not usually how you would look at this. As far as Composer's concerned, you're releasing a _package_, and that package happens to have a Drupal (sub)module in it which requires another package. So your "main" module's composer.json should contain the dependency. There's been a lot of manufactured crossover, but Drupal modules and Composer packages are still fundamentally different things, they don't match up 1-2-1

Comment: Well then I might follow what @cilefen suggested: separate the submodule into its own project. Cause I don't want people to have a dependency on Commerce core (which is pretty heavy) if they don't use the submodule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way for composer to check the dependency from your submodule.

Think about this. If somebody wants to install your submodule there is no way they can use a composer command to do it. They need to use the command to install the "main module" and is composer who handles the dependencies.

What happens now is your main module doesn't need the commerce module as a dependency and it will never be handled by composer while building the dependencies list to be downloaded. So your submodule will never have the dependencies it needs to work.

Two options:

- Commerce needs to be a dependency of your "main module"
- Your submodule needs to be a Drupal project in order the control the dependencies with composer.